# Rename Catalog and Cube name in Analyzer

Tags: pentaho, olap-cube

I have one query regarding pentaho cube:

Lets assume a cube (say sample ) with **schema name as schema1** and **cube name as cube1**. I **renamed**
that schema and cube to **schema2 and cube 2** respectively and published on schema workbench.

As my analyzer was earlier pointing to schema1 and cube1.. so inorder to make it functional, i also updated **catalog entry to schema2** and **cube entry to cube2**.

Now when i try to run analyzer it is showing following error in log:

com.pentaho.analyzer.service.e: Unable to find catalog: Sample
    at com.pentaho.analyzer.service.impl.OlapConnectionManagerImpl.createConnection(SourceFile:79)
    at com.pentaho.analyzer.service.impl.c.getConnection(SourceFile:31)
    at com.pentaho.analyzer.service.impl.OlapMetaDataManager.getConnection(SourceFile:49)

**Note: Well i have also checked the entry of corresponding catalog tag in datasource.xml under olap folder..**

so i my question is what else i need to configure inorder to make analyzer functional?

Answer (score 1):

I have repeated the same exercise.. now its working.. i simply refreshed pentaho.. may be earlier i forgot to refresh pentaho.